# Update multiple rows in SQL Server 2005 (v9.0.5000)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm currently creating a script automatically with a program that copies files from one place to another, and I used to do the following:

```
UPDATE d
SET Path = t.Path
FROM dbo.tableOperation d
JOIN (VALUES (1, 'Path 1'),
             (2, 'Path 2')) t (IdRegister, Path) ON t.IdRegister = d.IdRegister
```

And on SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50.1600) it was working fine, but I found some that the syntax has issues when trying to display the estimated execution plan of the script on the server I have to update the data (9.0.50000). The error specifically says

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'

I have to update tenths of thousands rows at a time, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to switch from `VALUES()` to `UNION ALL` for 2005 (will also work on 2008). But keep in mind support for SQL Server 2005 ended years ago. (I mean, that's so old I forgot `VALUES()` didn't exist there.) Time to move on?

```
UPDATE d
SET Path = t.Path
FROM dbo.tableOperation AS d
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 1,'Path 1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Path 2'
) AS t (IdRegister, Path) 
ON t.IdRegister = d.IdRegister;
```

Comment: I'd love to update it, but it's not really my call.

Comment: I made a test with a little over 27k rows, and it's taking a long while just to display the estimated execution plan, is there any way you think I can optimize the code?

Comment: @Throkar Maybe don't try to update 27K rows at a time using either approach? I would say 10K at a time is probably a decent upper bound here, maybe even less.

Comment: ...and either you need to update thousands and thousands of rows, or you don't. if you're going to pick an approach based on relative estimated execution plans, stop doing this by joining to a list of 27K+ constant values, and put those in a table. Then you can put keys, add indexes, benefit from stats, etc.

Comment: Well, basicly what I'm doing is to use a program I made to copy the files from one NAS to another, and I have to update the registers related to those files on the database and insert new registers that have certain requirements into another database, To do that I'm creating scripts in the code to run separately, so I tried to make this script to do a massive update whenever I'm done copying the files.

Comment: Still think you should just bulk insert the files instead of building some script that loops through them line by line...

Answer (score 0):

Good day Throkar,

Assuming that I understood your needs (which I am not totally sure), and since you are using hard-codes values using `(VALUES (1, 'Path 1'), (2, 'Path 2'))`, then maybe a simple direct update can solve your needs

Since you did not provided the DDL+DML I will use a basic demo

```
-- Let's assume that this our DDL+DML
drop table if exists tableOperation
GO
CREATE TABLE tableOperation(IdRegister int, Path varchar(100))
INSERT tableOperation(IdRegister) values (2),(4),(5)
select * from tableOperation
GO

--UPDATE d
--SET Path = t.Path
--FROM dbo.tableOperation d
--JOIN (VALUES (1, 'Path 1'),(2, 'Path 2')) t (IdRegister, Path) 
--  ON t.IdRegister = d.IdRegist

-- You can use this query
UPDATE dbo.tableOperation
SET Path = CASE   
    WHEN IdRegister = 1 then 'Path 1'
    WHEN IdRegister = 2 then 'Path 2'
END
WHERE IdRegister in (1,2)
```

In the filter (WHERE condition) I use hard-code list of all the values which you used in the ON condition, and in the SET section I simply use CASE statement with hard-code of conditions

Can this approach solve your needs?